# MATLAB- Copy text included between specific sentences from a file to another

Tags: regex, matlab, copy-paste

I have some scores after performing classification, that are saved in an ASCII file, which looks like this:

```
Time taken to build model: 0.39 seconds

=== Predictions on test data ===

inst#,    actual, predicted, error, probability distribution

     1 4:Walking_ 4:Walking_          0      0.015  0.061 *0.167  0.136  0.152  0.121  0.106  0.045  0.061  0.045  0.091
     2 4:Walking_ 4:Walking_          0      0.015  0.061 *0.167  0.136  0.152  0.121  0.106  0.045  0.061  0.045  0.091
     3 4:Walking_ 4:Walking_          0      0.015  0.045 *0.167  0.121  0.152  0.136  0.106  0.061  0.061  0.045  0.091
     4 4:Walking_ 4:Walking_          0      0.045  0.061 *0.167  0.121  0.152  0.136  0.106  0.015  0.03   0.076  0.091
     5 4:Walking_ 4:Walking_          0      0.03   0.061 *0.167  0.136  0.152  0.121  0.106  0.03   0.061  0.045  0.091
     6 10:jumping  9:running      +   0      0.03   0.045  0.106  0.121  0.136  0.091  0.076 *0.167  0.152  0.03   0.045

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===
```

What I want is to read through the file and copy all contents between the lines inst#,actual,... and ===stratified cross validation=== to another file. A solution using regular expression is the most suitable, since the size of the file varies. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is to use `fscanf` and `fprintf`. As in the following:

```
clear all 

fid = fopen('prova');

data = fscanf(fid,'%*[^=]%*[^\n]%[^=]',1);

fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('new','w');

fprintf(fid,'%c',data);

fclose(fid);
```

This of course works only if you do not use `=` in the data fields.